# Function for adding item to the end of a linked list

Tags: python, linked-list

I'm new to programming in general and have just started using python. I have recently been learning about linked lists and I was having trouble using a function to add an item to the end of my list. The function listed below called addToTail isn't working and is giving me the error: TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

```
def addToHead(myList, value):
    node = {}
    node['data'] = value
    node['next'] = myList
    return node

def addToTail(myList, value):
    ptr = myList
    while ptr != None:
         ptr = ptr['next']
    node = {}
    node['data'] = value
    node['next'] = None
    ptr['next'] = node 
    return myList

def printList(myList):
    ptr = myList
    while ptr != None:
        print(ptr['data'])
        ptr = ptr['next']
    print('None')

def createList(pythonList):
    linkedList = None
    for i in pythonList:
        linkedList = addToHead(linkedList, i)
    return linkedList



firstList = createList([5, 10, 15])
addToTail(firstList, 10)
printList(firstList)
```

Comment: Since you are stepping your pointer, you are ending up pointing at `None` always, before trying to add a new element. You need to keep a trailing pointer around, that will be pointing to the previous last element, in order to have that element point at your new last one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `addToTail` will always have the pointer as None, because you're iterating until your value is none in your while loop. Add an extra variable that points to the previous element in the linked list instead- That way, you'll get the last value in the list instead of None.

```
def addToTail(myList, value):
    ptr = myList
    prev = ptr
    while ptr != None:
         prev = ptr
         ptr = ptr['next']
    node = {}
    node['data'] = value
    node['next'] = None
    prev['next'] = node 
    return myList
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue lies with this part of `addToTail()` function:

```
ptr = myList
while ptr != None:
     ptr = ptr['next']
```

You're essentially looping until there is no next node and `ptr` is set to `None`. Then later on when you try to assign the node with `ptr['next'] = node` it obviously fails as you're trying to access `None`, not the tail node. You can solve this (to keep with your style) by checking for the next item prior to the assignment:

```
ptr = myList
while True:
    if ptr['next'] is None:
        break
    ptr = ptr['next']
```